# Plotly: Plotting word frequency of user input by year from csv

Tags: python, python-3.x, plotly

I want to plot the word usage over time of words from a user input. E.g. user enters "begab, social, demokrat". These terms are stored in the variable `u_input`. I want to use the `startswith()` method to include words like "social, socialismus, socialreform" while using the term "social" etc.

As preparation I merged 2300 xml files of a historical prussian newspaper corpus into csv files with information about "year, word, count":

```
year| word        | count
----|-------------|----
1864|befürchtete  |1
1864|befürchtungen|1
1864|begab        |1
1864|begab        |2
1864|begab        |3
1864|begab        |5
1864|begaben      |1
1864|begaben      |3
1865|begab        |2
1865|begab        |2
```

I then used Pandas to group the data so that the total count of a word for each year is available and saved the data as a new csv file "pandas_dict.csv":

```
year| word        | count
----|-------------|----
1864|befürchtete  |1
1864|befürchtungen|1
1864|begab        |11
1864|begaben      |4
1865|begab        |4
```

I now would like to use plotly (offline) to plot one figure that shows the word usage graphs for the sample terms "social, conserv, kommuni". (Reason: In this example I want to compare the newspaper coverage for the socialist party, the conservatives and the communists, more specifically the general prominence of words associated with the parties, hence everything "social" or "k[c]ommunist".)

Unfortunately the code from all the examples I read wouldn't work, since none of the ones I could find included any kind of mechanic to only show graphs for the terms in `u_input`.

```
import plotly as py
import plotly.graph_objs as go
import pandas as pd

# Create DataFrame from prepared csv
df = pd.read_csv(self.dir + self.dict_dir + 'pandas_dict.csv', header=None, names=['year', 'word', 'count'])
# define data for plotting - how do I incorporate u_input?
trace1 = go.Scatter(x=df['year'], y=df['count'], mode='lines', name='test')

layout = go.Layout(title='Word usage over time', plot_bgcolor='rgb(230, 230,230)')
fig = go.Figure(data=[trace1], layout=layout)

# Plot data
py.offline.plot(fig)
```

Here is an older example I created with NLTK, that shows roughly what I imagine to do with plotly:
[image: word usage over time in american inaugural speeches]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- You could first filter your dataframe for each word (`df[df['word'].str.contains(word)]` via `contains`
- Next group everything by year via `groupby`
- Finally report only 'count' and sum it (`['count'].aggregate(sum)`)
- In order to plot it, iterate over your words in `u_input` and add a trace for each word,

---

```
import pandas as pd
import plotly
import io

txt="""year|word|count
1864|befürchtete|1
1864|befürchtungen|1
1864|begab|11
1864|begaben|4
1865|begab|4
1864|kommuni|3
1864|social|2
1864|conserv|5
1865|kommuni|6
1865|social|3
1865|conserv|4
1866|kommuni|8
1866|social|2
1866|conserv|6
1867|conservativ|4
1867|conservative|1
1867|socialist|1
1867|socialisti|2
1867|nonsense|99
1867|kommunist|4
1867|kommuni|2
"""

u_input = ['kommuni', 'social', 'conserv']

df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(txt), sep='|')

#filter the dataframe according to u_input
df = df[df['word'].str.contains('|'.join(u_input))]

traces = [plotly.graph_objs.Scatter(x=df['year'][df['word'].str.contains(word)],
                                    y=df[df['word'].str.contains(word)].groupby(['year'])['count'].aggregate(sum),
                                    name=word, mode='lines') for word in u_input]

layout = plotly.graph_objs.Layout(xaxis=dict(tickvals=df['year'].unique()))
fig = plotly.graph_objs.Figure(data=traces, layout=layout)
plotly.offline.plot(fig)
```

Comment: Close, but not quite. If I add words like "conservative" to the list of words and don't change the u_input (= 'conserv'), "conservative" is not included in the counts for "conserv". Everything else works nicely.

Comment: Unfortunately it still doesn't work (I also tried this exact version yesterday and couldn't figure out what's wrong). If you add "1867|kommuni|20" and "1867|kommunis|2" add the end of the list then the graph jumps to all 3 values, first to 6, then draws the line to 20 and then to 2). It doesn't add the counts.

Comment: Ah, I think slowly I get how your real data looks like. You need to first sum your data based on the word pattern and then plot it? Try the updated answer.

Comment: Works perfectly for the given test data, but not my real data. No idea why, but the graph is sill messed up. I made a workaround and can use that to get a satisfieing result. All that said, since it works with the test data I'll mark this as the correct answer.